# No shortcut for DDMS in Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, ddms, android-studio-2.2

After updating Android studio to version 2.2, I am not able to find option of DDMS in the toolbar.
Though I can find it in *Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor*.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: yes, it is removed in Android studio 2.2

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is easy to get it back. Just follow the steps below:

Step 1: Go to File-> Settings

[image]

Step 2: Select Menus and Toolbars -> Main Toolbar

[image]

Step 3: Under Main Toolbar select AndroidMainActionToolbarGroup and click Add After button.

[image]

Step 4: Select Main Menu - > Tools

[image]

Step 5: Under Tools Select Android

[image]

Step 6: Under Android Select Android Device Monitor and click on Ok button and again click on ok on Settings window.

[image]

You should be good to go now. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the walkthrough with pictures! but it didn't make me lol ;)

Answer (score 8):

This is some shortcut way to do that:

1. Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor
2. Ctrl+Shif+A -> search for Android Device Monitor

You should see the Android Device Monitor.

Answer (score 3):

Just type **"monitor"** in the search box that's it.

[image: See the screen shot]